# Solving triangular matrix equations on a GPU

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, cuda, banded-matrix

Suppose I have these two $N\times N$ lower triangular banded matrices:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_0 & &  \\
a_1 & a_0 & \\
a_2 & a_1 & a_0 \\
a_3 & a_2 & a_1 & a_0 \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & a_3 & a_2 & a_1 & a_0
\end{bmatrix}$
$B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & &  \\
b_1 & 1 & \\
b_2 & b_1 & 1 \\
b_3 & b_2 & b_1 & 1 \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
& & b_3 & b_2 & b_1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Let $x$ and $y$ be vectors of size $N$. Given vector $x$, i need to obtain $y$ through the following matrix operations:

$y = \left(B^T\right)^{-1}A^TB^{-1}Ax$

For the inverse operations, I am using forward and backward substitutions for $B^{-1}$ and $\left(B^T\right)^{-1}$, respectively. I have several independent $x$ vectors that I need to process, and I am doing all of this on a GPU with CUDA. Each CUDA thread is responsible for a single $x$ to $y$ operation.

However, I want to parallelize this by applying several CUDA threads to operate on a single $x$ vector. This lets me use shared memory as "temporary work vectors" and minimize global memory accesses. I also won't ever have a case where vectors of size $N$ are too large to fit in shared memory.

The problem is that it appears tricky to parallelize the forward/substitutions, I was wondering if

1) Is there a mathematical trick to simplify the above matrix equations? As in, only having to do one inverse operation instead of two.

Or

2) Is there a better way to invert my two B matrices? Like a more parallel friendly direct solver, or iterative solver, that lets multiple CUDA threads operate on the same vector?

Side note, the coefficient $b_1$ will vary somewhere between 1 and 2, whereas $b_2$ and $b_3$ both vary between 0 and 1. Thus B is not diagonally dominant.

EDIT: following up to Federico's suggestion, if my system can be rewritten as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & B \\
B^T & A
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
b \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $b = Ax$, and if I invert the $2\times 2$ block system, I get the following:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\left.\begin{bmatrix}
0 & B \\
B^T & A^T
\end{bmatrix}\right. ^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
b \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Could the inverted $2\times 2$ be rewritten as:
$$\left.\begin{bmatrix}
0 & B \\
B^T & A^T
\end{bmatrix}\right. ^{-1}
=
\left(\frac{1}{0\cdot A^T - B^TB}\right)
\begin{bmatrix}
A^T & -B^T \\
-B & 0
\end{bmatrix}\\
=-\left(B^TB\right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
A^T & -B^T \\
-B & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus the solution $y$ would be as simple as:
$$y = -\left(B^TB\right)^{-1}A^Tb = -\left(B^TB\right)^{-1}A^TAx $$
Does this make logical sense? It doesn't seem clear to me how the above is equivalent to 
$$y = \left(B^T\right)^{-1}A^TB^{-1}Ax$$

Edit2: actually the above doesn’t make sense at all. I think what I did only applies if $A$ and $B$ were scalars. I’m still wondering if it’s possible to do only one inverse/solve operation (even if it means losing the triangular sparsity pattern), thus opening up the possibility of using preconditioned iterative solvers which might be more amenable to GPUs

Comment: As you suspect, the formula for the inverse of a $2\times 2$ system only holds for scalars, not blocks; so your computations are invalid, unfortunately. But you are mis-interpreting my suggestion; don't try to compute that inverse symbolically. Take that $2N\times 2N$ matrix and pass it directly to your solver. That's your "only one inverse/solve operation"; the only catch is that the matrix you are going to pass to your solver is a bit larger. This won't be a huge issue, since the number of nonzeros has a more important role than the size when dealing with sparse matrices.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thanks, I’ll give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is there a mathematical trick to simplify the above matrix equations? As in, only having to do one inverse operation instead of two.

Yes: Schur complement formulation. Your system is equivalent to the larger one

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & B\\
B^T & A^T
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-b\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $b=Ax$ (which you can simply compute) and $z=-B^{-1}b$.

The idea is that one constructs a block-$2\times 2$ matrix whose Schur complement is the system matrix to be inverted, $-BA^{-T}B^T$ (up to a sign).

This matrix is no longer triangular, but I would guess that by reversing the order of unknowns in some of the blocks you can reduce it to a triangular or anti-triangular matrix, which you can then solve by direct substitution. If you are lucky maybe you can end up with a banded block-$2\times 2$ matrix. So this answer is not the end of the story; try some more manipulations to get a simpler form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i can definitely see how this can be expressed as a Schur Complement. However, isn’t A^-T a dense matrix that needs to be calculated for explicitly? So doesn’t that mean I still need two inverse operations, one for A and then one for the Schur Complement?

Comment: No, you don't need to compute $A^{-T}$. You just solve the $2\times 2$ system in my displayed equation.

Comment: Can you check my edited post? I am not sure if my logic w.r.t. solving the $2\times 2$ system works.

Comment: @Justin Done, I have commented under it.